# AngularJs watch window variable

Tags: angularjs

In angularJs is possible to watch a global variable?

I set a window.test variable from legacy code, then I need to watch that variable to know if it exists.

I've tried something like

```
$window.$watch("test" , function(n,o){
    //some code here...
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Somewhat.  You can if you include the Angular [`$window` service](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.%24window) (which is safer, as explained in the docs, than accessing `window` directly):

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$window) {...}
```

And then use a watch function as the first parameter to your [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) like so:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function () {
        return $window.test 
    }, function(n,o){
        console.log("changed ",n);
    }
);
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s624Q/1/)

But note that the `$watch` won't execute until something triggers Angular to do a $digest.  One possible way to do that is to wrap your legacy code in a `$scope.$apply` or trigger a `$digest` once the legacy code has exectuted.  Here's some good [documentation on this](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html).

Basically whenever a change happens outside of angular (for instance this is a common issue when jQuery causes the change) something has to tell Angular to go see if something changed.  It's one way Angular maintains reasonable performance.

Comment: Will this work if it is changed outside of the scope of angular, such as it would in legacy code?

Comment: Updated with more details on that.

Comment: One other thing to note is that this will only trigger if the value of $window.test itself changes - either a primitive type (number, string,  date, boolean, etc) changing values, or an object reference changing. If you want it to trigger if a property of $window.test changes, you'll need to pass `true` as the 3rd param of $watch() so that angular will check the properties instead of just equality.

Comment: Nice call. In my case, I used a $rootScope.$watch() this way to enable/disable logging in built or production instances of Angular apps by running "window.logging_required = true/false" in the JS console. Super useful. Thanks @KayakDave !