# Trigger $digest when variable changed by node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, node-webkit

I want to make an application with node-webkit using AngularJS.
No problem so far but when I want Angular to watch over a "legacy variable" by using the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667213/1382768) I just get an `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`.

I wrapped my node.js function into `$scope.$apply()` like this:

```
$scope.$apply(myNodeModule("test", function(err, res) {
        if (err) {return console.log(err)}
        myLegacyVar = res;
}));
```

And watching over the (global) `myLegacyVar` variable like described in the answer mentioned before:

```
function () {
            return $window.myLegacyVar
        }, function(n,o){
            console.log("changed ",n);
            $scope.data = n;
        }
);
```

All of the code resides within my Angular controller function.

The function is async, so I guess it could have to do with that?
Or is this function inception I have going on in $apply maybe causing my error?

I'm just clueless right now, I have just recently started using AngularJS, hours of googleing haven't gotten my very far.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18265285/1382768) helped. The safe $apply function there did the trick.
I added that function to my controller and added this snipped to my node.js function:

```
var scope = angular.element($("#angularDOMElement")).scope();
scope.safeApply(function(){
    myLegacyVar = res;
})
```

I don't know if thats the proper way to do it but its working.