# Access Global javascript variables inside AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on a site, and I started building it before I realized I needed some dynamic framework. After learning about AngularJS, I decided to use it, where I needed (not the whole site).

I have a very long script in JS, and I want to be able to get and set the variables from within AngularJS directives and controllers.

**I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive) answer,** and it was quite good - I was able to get the variable from within the function. But when the variable changed outside the function, AngularJS' variable won't update.

My code looked something like this:

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('someName', []);
var currentPage = 'Menu';

app.controller('PageController', ['$window','$scope', function($window,$scope){

    this.currentPage = $window.currentPage;

    this.isPage = function(page){
        return (page == this.currentPage);
    };
}]);


function button1onClick(){
    currentPage = 'Game';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="PageController">
    <div id="Game" ng-show="page.isPage('Game')">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="Menu" ng-show="page.isPage('Menu')">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

(button1onClick was called when I clicked some button on the page)

The idea is that I have two dives I want to switch between, using a globle variable. 'Menu' page was visible at first but upon clicking I was supposed to see only the 'Game' div.

The variable inside the controller didn't upadte, but was only given the initial value of `currentPage`.

I decided to use the `$window` service inside the `isPage` function, but this didn't work either. Only when I called a function that tested the $window.currentPage variable, the pages switched - like I wanted:

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('someName', []);

var currentPage = 'Menu';

app.controller('PageController', ['$window','$scope', function($window,$scope){

    this.isPage = function(page){
        return (page == $window.currentPage);
    };

    this.button2onClick = function() {
        $window.alert($window.currentPage);
    }
}]);


function button1onClick(){
    currentPage = 'Game';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="button1onClick()">CLICK ME</button> //Button 1
<div ng-controller="PageController">
    <button ng-click="page.button2onClick">CLICK ME</button> //Button 2

    <div id="Game" ng-show="page.isPage('Game')">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="Menu" ng-show="page.isPage('Menu')">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

So the only way I was able to update the pages is to call a function that tests the variable, thus updating the variable in AngularJS.

Is there a way to access a global variable without needing to test it to update it?

Am I doing something wrong? I don't want to convert my whole site to AngularJS-style, I like the code the way it is. Is AngularJS not the framework for me?

**EDIT:**

some things to clear out:

1. I'm new to AngularJS, so if you could explain what your answer does it would be great.
2. The whole reason why I do this instead of redirecting to another page is not to shut down socket.io 's connection

Comment: i think you want to watch the var - try this prev answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667012/angularjs-watch-window-variable

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but I think it's worth mentioning that you should consider refactoring. Angular is a framework and a methodology. I think you're going to run into these situations quite a bit and in the long run, will end up with a better, more maintainable app, if you refactor to use Angular. Your logic will stay relatively the same. I've done this before on a relatively modestly sized existing site and it took a day and a half or so. I was an Angular nOOb at the time and it really helped me learn Angular.

Comment: @MikeFeltman I understand why this is good, but I am using socket.io to keep the client connected (this is game site, requiring constant connection like chat), and I don't know if I can keep my code with both socket.io and AngularJS. PLUS, I can't seem to find anywhere how to write a normal webpage using Angular's structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading **[malix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37054573/2331046)** and **[KKKKKKKK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37054648/2331046)**, and after researching a bit, I was able to solve my problem, and even write a better looking code.

**To switch divs** as I wanted in the example, I used [**ui-router**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), almost exactly the way KKKKKKKK did. The only difference is that I change state programmaticly - `$state.go('menu')`

**To access global variables** in other places in my code, I had to re-structure my whole code to fit AngularJS's structure, and used a **[Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)**, similarly to malix's answer:

```
app.factory('Data', function(){
    var Data = {};
        //DEFINE DATA
    Data.stateChange = function(){};
    Data.menuData = {};
    Data.randomColors = ['#35cd96', '#6bcbef', '#E8E1DA', '#91ab01'];
        /RETURN DATA
    return Data;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

OP, take a look at [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

    $stateProvider.state('main', {
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        url: '/main/'
    }).state('game', {
        controller: 'GameCtrl',
        url: '/game/',
        templateUrl: 'game.html'
    });
}]);
```

**HTML links:**

```
<a ui-sref="main">Go to Main</a>
<a ui-sref="game">Go to Game</a>
```

**View injection**

```
<div ui-view="">
</div>
```

Comment: @malix Okay, I think I know what OP wants.  He'd be interested in ui.router.

Comment: Yep. I agree. It doesn't answer his question but it fits his motive perfectly!

Comment: This actually worked pretty well, and is exactly what I was looking for, but two things seem to be missing:

--- 1. I still can't use global variables, the code I showed was only one of many places I needed global variable in my code, and 

 --- 2. is there a way to change the ui-sref programmaticly, like `app.state="game"`?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `$window` as a map object.
You should probably create a PageService:

```
angular.module('someName')
  .factory('Page', [function(){
    var currentPage = 'Menu';
    return {
      getPage: function() {
        return currentPage;
      },
      isPage: function(page) {
        return page === currentPage;
      },
      setPage: function(page) {
        currentPage = page;
      }
    }
  }]);

app.controller('PageController', ['Page','$scope', function(Page,$scope){

  this.currentPage = Page.getPage();
  this.isPage = Page.isPage;
  this.button10Click = function(){
    Page.setPage('Game');
  }
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="button" ng-click="page.button10Click()">Game</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer turned out to be exactly what I needed to get and set variables.
My only question is why do you use `setPage` and `getPage` when you can just return the variable? (look at my answer)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using $rootScope. Variable initialize once can be accessible in other controllers.

```
function Ctrl1($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.GlobalJSVariableA= window.GlobalJSVariable;  }
```

Any controller & any view can access it now

```
function CtrlN($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.GlobalJSVariableA= $rootScope.GlobalJSVariableA; 
}
```